# Is there a network mapping tool for path-loss?

Tags: communication, digital-communications, telecommunications

I am not sure if this is the proper forum. I am looking for a tool to evaluate the wireless network performance.For example, given a map where should I put a transmitter/or transmitter plus repeater so that the map area is covered by the transmitter. Another example may be given a map and a transmitter location how the signal strength will vary at the different locations of the map?

Comment: Without the use of direct line of site, and a tower for the host antenna, there will always a huge variation in path loss from unexpected reflections and Ricean fading Loss which can be detected by RSSI signals programs such Xirrus WiFi Inspector with a stripchart like record in time of signals.  This is useful for doing surveys.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I am looking for some tool, useful for indoor as well. I can understand the possible variations.

Comment: it is not useful for indoors as material modeling a building is impossible.  There are simply too many reflections..  just use Xirrus and beware that even a 1mm movement out of a null spot can make 10 dB difference from -80 to -70 dBm.  Read Ricean Fading

Comment: The Log-distance model can be useful for indoor estimates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-distance_path_loss_model. As Tony points out, fading is a concern, so the Log-distance model handles this with a random variable. Indoor propagation modeling is more an educated guess than an exact science, though.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is known as a [radio propagation model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_propagation_model), which can range from very simple paper calculations (eg: free-space path loss, two-ray model, Hata models) to much more complicated software solutions which take digital elevation models as inputs and return path loss contours as outputs.

There are many propagation models in the second group, some of which can be quite specialized and expensive. The [Longley-Rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longley%E2%80%93Rice_model) model is probably the best known open-source model, and there are several free software implementations of it, such as [SPLAT](http://www.qsl.net/kd2bd/splat.html).